# Static Library C++/WinRT

Tags: c++-winrt

I have created a static library(c++/WinRT) and an Universal Windows App [Blank App] (c++/WinRT)project in VS 2019.

Then From Project Universal Window app I added project reference of the static library.

I am getting below error while building the universal app

```
D:\Dv\Main\Vib\CM\UI\UserInterfaceCppWinRT\Generated Files\XamlTypeInfo.g.cpp(178,52): error C2039: 'UIViewModelCppWinRT': is not a member of 'winrt'
```

Individually the static library build successfully. Not getting any clue about c++/winrt static library project consumption. Any suggestion?

Comment: I created a c++/winrt uwp app and a static library(c++/winrt), when I added the reference of the static library, then built the main project, it worked well, didn't throwed any exception. Can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test?

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT Yes, it certainly does work. My environment has some custom props. I guess I am messed up with default props and custom props. I will update the post with additional clue if needed. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT are you able to import any idl from the library to the app? For example the default library project has a Class.idl How can I import it in the app mainpage.idl and access the class properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add reference of the static library to main project and build main project successfully, you can find it has generated the **StaticLibrary.h** file under the **\MyProject\MyProject\Generated Files\winrt** folder along with other Windows namespaces. So if you want to import the idl(e.g. Class.idl), you don't need to import it manually, since your toolchain is set up to automatically reference any types that are in system namespaces. You only need to import any types that you've defined in your project. For example:

MainPage.idl

```
namespace WinrtApp
{
    [default_interface]
    runtimeclass MainPage : Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page
    {
        MainPage();
        Int32 MyProperty;
        StaticLibrary1.Class MyClass;
    }
}
```

When you want to access the property from static library, first include the header file and initialize it.

MainPage.h

```
private:
        StaticLibrary1::Class myclass{nullptr};
```

.cpp:

```
#include "winrt/StaticLibrary1.h"

myclass = StaticLibrary1::Class();
int property = myclass.MyProperty();
```

[Here](https://github.com/wcj233/StaticLibraryApp) is a simple sample that I created, you can download it to check the complete steps.